# Is it possible to implement MonadFix for `Free`?

Tags: haskell, monadfix, free-monad

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free in `Control.Monad.Free.Free` allows one to get access to the "free monad" for any given `Functor`.  It does not, however, have a `MonadFix` instance.  Is this because such an instance cannot be written, or was it just left out?

If such an instance cannot be written, why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the description of what `mfix` does:

> The fixed point of a monadic computation. `mfix f` executes the action `f` only once, with the eventual output fed back as the input.

The word "executes", in the context of `Free`, means creating layers of the `Functor`. Thus, "only once" means that in the result of evaluating `mfix f`, the values held in `Pure` constructors must fully determine how many layers of the functor are created.

Now, say we have a specific function `once` that we know will always only create a single `Free` constructor, plus however many `Pure` constructors are needed to hold the leaf values. The output of 'once', then, will be only values of type `Free f a` that are isomorphic to some value of type `f a`. With this knowledge, we can un-`Free` the output of `once` safely, to get a value of type `f a`.

Now, note that because `mfix` is required to "execute the action only once", the result of `mfix once` should, for a conforming instance, contain no additional monadic structure than `once` creates in a single application. Thus we can deduce that the value obtained from `mfix once` must also be isomorphic to a value of type `f a`.

Given any function with type `a -> f a` for some `Functor` `f`, we can wrap the result with a single `Free` and get a function of type `a -> Free f a` which satisfies the description of `once` above, and we've already established that we can unwrap the result of `mfix once` to get a value of type `f a` back.

Therefore, a conforming instance `(Functor f) => MonadFix (Free f)` would imply being able to write, via the wrapping and unwrapping described above, a function `ffix :: (Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> f a` that would work for all instances of `Functor`.

That's obviously not a proof that you *can't* write such an instance... but if it were possible, `MonadFix` would be completely superfluous, because you could just as easily write `ffix` directly. (And I suppose reimplement it as `mfix` with a `Monad` constraint, using `liftM`. Ugh.)

Comment: So far I've found that if I can implement `retractFunctor :: f a -> a` for a given `f`, then I can implement `mfix f = fix (f . iter retractFunctor)`.  I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: @singpolyma: My initial thought was that it should at least be possible to write the instance `(Functor m, MonadFix m) => MonadFix (Free m)`. But I couldn't figure out how to do so correctly.

Comment: This result also makes sense because "free" means that it's supposed to give you a monad *and nothing more*. But `MonadFix` is not part of `Monad` and, indeed, if `Monad` implied it then it would be superfluous. Could you make a "free `MonadFix`" by adding additional structure to `Free`? (My naive attempt was brought up short when it came to writing `fmap` for the `Fix (a -> Free f a)` constructor...)

Comment: @illissius: Yeah, you probably won't get very far having the type parameter in contravariant position... I'd have to think about it, I was more concerned with figuring out what extra structure on `f` would allow `mfix`, not using something other than `Free`.

Comment: @illissius, you could make a free monadfix by adding to `Free` the constructor `forall s. Fix (s -> Free f (s,a))`.  It would not strictly satisfy the laws; however, that can be patched up by requiring properties for something to be a valid consumer (some formal variant of "it can make no important decisions based on seeing a `Fix` constructor"; e.g. one of them might be `f (Fix (\s -> Pure (s,x)) = f (Pure x)`).

Comment: Maybe if you take a functor from the category of monads with mfixes, such the monad homomorphisms have some sort of respect of the mfixes, to the category of functors, forgetfully, you could get some sort of "left adjunct" thingy.

Answer (score 5):

Well, inspired by the `MonadFix` instance for `Maybe`, I tried this one (using the following definitions of `Free`):

```
data Free f a
    = Pure a
    | Impure (f (Free f a))

instance (Functor f) => Monad (Free f) where
    return = Pure
    Pure x >>= f = f x
    Impure x >>= f = Impure (fmap (>>= f) x)

instance (Functor f) => MonadFix (Free f) where
    mfix f = let Pure x = f x in Pure x
```

[The laws](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad-Fix.html) are:

- Purity: `mfix (return . h) = return (fix h)`
- Left shrinking: `mfix (\x -> a >>= \y -> f x y) = a >>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)`
- Sliding: `mfix (liftM h . f) = liftM h (mfix (f . h))`, for strict `h`
- Nesting: `mfix (\x -> mfix (f x)) = mfix (\x -> f x x)`

Purity is easy to prove -- but I came across a problem when trying to prove left shrinking:

```
mfix (\x -> a >>= \y -> f x y)
= let Pure x = (\x -> a >>= \y -> f x y) x in Pure x
= let Pure x = a >>= \y -> f x y in Pure x
-- case a = Pure z
  = let Pure x = Pure z >>= \y -> f x y in Pure x
  = let Pure x = f x z in Pure x
  = let Pure x = (\x -> f x z) x in Pure x
  = mfix (\x -> f x z)
  = Pure z >>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)
-- case a = Impure t
  = let Pure x = Impure t >>= \y -> f x y in Pure x
  = let Pure x = Impure (fmap (>>= \y -> f x y) t) in Pure x
  = Pure _|_
```

but

```
  Impure t >>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)
  = Impure (fmap (>>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)) t)
  /= Pure _|_
```

So, at the very least, if the `Pure` and `Impure` constructors are distinguishable, then my implementation of `mfix` does not satisfy the laws.  I can't think of any other implementation, but that does not mean it does not exist.   Sorry I couldn't illuminate further.

Comment: I'm having a thought -- what if distinguishing `Pure` and `Impure` is not something you're supposed to be able to do; i.e. it *feels* like, categorically speaking, `Free Identity` should be isomorphic to `Identity`.  Category-privy, am I on base?

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be written in general, because not every Monad is an instance of MonadFix.
Every Monad can be implemented using the FreeMonad underneath. If you could implement the MonadFix for Free, then you would be able to derive MonadFix from any Monad, which is not possible.
But of course, you can define a FreeFix for the MonadFix class.

I think it might look somehow like this, but this is just a 3rd guess (still not tested):

```
data FreeFix m a = FreeFix { runFreeFix :: (forall r. (r -> m r) -> m r) -> m a }

instance (Monad m) => Monad (FreeFix m) where
    return a = FreeFix $ \_-> do
        return a
    f >>= g = FreeFix $ \mfx -> do
        x <- runFreeFix f mfx
        runFreeFix (g x) mfx

instance (Monad m) => MonadFix (FreeFix m) where
    mfix f = FreeFix $ \mfx -> do
        mfx (\r->runFreeFix (f r) mfx)
```

The idea is that m is a Monad that lacks an implementation for mfix; so mfix needs to be a parameter when FreeFix will be reduced.

Comment: `FreeFix m` is not a functor.  But you can make it one using the technique of Arrow's `loop` combinator: `| forall r. Fix (r -> FreeFix m (r,a))`.

Comment: @luqui: somehow i got this recursion scheme from your suggestion, don't know how.