# What monads can be expressed as Free over some functor?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, free-monad

The [documentation for `Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free) says:

> A number of common monads arise as free monads,
>
> - Given `data Empty a`, `Free Empty` is isomorphic to the `Identity` monad.
> - Free `Maybe` can be used to model a partiality monad where each layer represents running the computation for a while longer.

**What other monads are expressible using `Free`?**

I could think only of one more: I believe `Free (Const e)` is isomorphic to `Either e`.

**Edit: What monads are *not* expressible using `Free` and why?**

Comment: lists and trees are expressible using `Free`; this is demonstrated in the classic paper http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/mpc08.pdf.  I'd expect there are a good deal more, but I'm not the one to provide an authoritative answer.

Comment: Do you mean `Free Identity` rather than `Free Maybe`?

Comment: @shachaf I just quoted the documentation of `Free`. I'm not really sure what is meant by _where each layer represents running the computation for a while longer_, so I cannot judge.

Comment: Either that documentation is mixed up or I am. At any rate, one more example for you -- `Free Proxy` is `Maybe`, where `data Proxy a = Proxy`.

Comment: @shachaf: If I understand correctly (though I may not), it has to do with partiality.  `val` is a value. `Just val` is a computation that completed in one step, `Nothing` indicates that the computation ran for one step and couldn't complete. `Just (Just val)` completed in two steps, `Just Nothing` ran for two steps and couldn't complete. And so on and so forth.  Each layer of `Free` is one more elapsed time step.  (More precisely those should be `Pure val`, `Free (Just (Pure val))`, `Free Nothing`, `Free (Just (Free (Just (Pure val))))`, and `Free (Just (Free Nothing))`, respectively.)

Comment: @JohnL Free monads capture exactly leaf-labelled tree structures, indeed giving Janis an example. But lists are another kettle of fish. Whilst Free ((,) a) () is a copy of [a], it doesn't expose the *monad* structure of lists, rather the *monoid* structure: (>>=) concatenates, as ever with free monads, by grafting at the leaf.

Comment: It's slightly troubling to say that Free Identity is a "partiality monad", in that it collapses (as does Haskell, of course) the conceptual difference between inductive and coinductive data. In more discerning settings, Free f x is the *inductive* type mu y. x + f y, containing trees of finite depth. The *coinductive* type nu y. x + f y, allowing infinite depth (as required for partiality), is called the *completely iterative* monad. Even if Haskell does not express this distinction, we should make it, in the expectation that language expressivity will catch up with us.

Comment: @shachaf: No, it should be `Free Maybe`. The idea is that a value of a lifted type `a` (which could be bottom) can be encoded as a coinductive `Free Maybe a` where `Pure` means it evaluated to a defined value, `Free Nothing` means it ended with an explicit error, and `Free (Just ...)` means it's not done evaluating. The layers of `Free` separate each recursive call, and non-termination results in nothing else.

Comment: @pigworker of course you're correct, thanks.  I need to learn to reason just a bit more before hitting enter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Almost all of them (up to issues involving looping and `mfix`) but not `Cont`.

Consider the `State` monad

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (a,s))
```

does not look *anything* like a free monad... but think about `State` in terms of *how you use it*

```
get :: m s --or equivalently (s -> m a) -> m a
set :: s -> m () --or (s,m a) -> m a
runState :: m a -> s -> (a,s)
```

we can design a free monad with this interface by listing the operations as constructors

```
data StateF s a
  = Get (s -> a) | Set s a deriving Functor
```

then we have

```
type State s a = Free (StateF s) a
```

with

```
get = Impure (Get Pure)
set x = Impure (Set x (Pure ())
```

and we just need a way to use it

```
runState (Pure a) s = (a,s)
runState (Impure (Get f)) s = runState (f s) s
runState (Impure (Set s next)) _ = runState next s
```

you can do this construction with most monads.  Like the maybe/partiality monad is defined by

```
stop :: m a
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> m a -> b
```

the rule is, we treat each of the functions that end in `m x` for some `x` as a constructor in the functor, and the other functions are ways of running the resulting free monad.  In this case

```
data StopF a = StopF deriving Functor

maybe _ f (Pure a)      = f a
maybe b _ (Impure Stop) = b
```

why is this cool?  Well a few things

1. The free monad gives you a piece of *data* that you can think of as being an AST for the monadic code.  You can write functions that operate on this data which is really useful for DSLs
2. Functors compose, which means breaking down your monads like this makes them semi composeable.  In particular, given two functors which share an algebra (an algebra is essentially just a function `f a -> a` for some `a` when `f` is a functor), the composition also has that algebra.

<strike>Functor composition is just</strike> We can combine functors in several ways, most of which preserve that algebra.  In this case we want not the *composition of functors* `(f (g (x)))` but the *functor coproduct*.  Functors *add*

```
data f :+: g a = Inl (f a) | Inr (g a) 

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :+: g) where
  fmap f (Inl x) = Inl (fmap f x)
  fmap f (Inr x) = Inr (fmap f x)

compAlg :: (f a -> a) -> (g a -> a) -> f :+: g a -> a
compAlg f _ (Inl x) = f x
compAlf _ g (Inr x) = g x
```

also free monads preserve algebras

```
freeAlg :: (f a -> a) -> Free f a -> a
freeAlg _ (Pure a) = a
freeAlg f (Impure x) = f $ fmap (freeAlg f) x
```

In Wouter Swierstra's famous paper [Data Types A La Carte](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) this is used to great effect.  A simple example from that paper is the calculator.  Which we will take a monadic take on new to this post.  Given the algebra

```
class Calculator f where
 eval :: f Integer -> Integer
```

we can think of various instances

```
data Mult a = Mult a a deriving Functor
instance Calculator Mult where
  eval (Mult a b) = a*b

data Add a = Add a a deriving Functor
instance Calculator Add where
  eval (Add a b) = a+b

data Neg a = Neg a deriving Functor
instance Calculator Neg where
  eval (Neg a) = negate a

instance Calculator (Const Integer) where
  eval (Const a) = a

data Signum a = Signum a deriving Functor
instance Calculator Signum where
  eval (Signum a) = signum a

data Abs a = Abs a deriving Functor
instance Calculator Abs where
  eval (Abs a) = abs a
```

and the most important

```
instance (Calculator f, Calculator g) => Calculator (f :+: g) where
   eval = compAlg eval
```

you can define the *numeric monad*

```
newtype Numerical a = Numerical (
        Free (Mult 
        :+: Add 
        :+: Neg 
        :+: Const Integer 
        :+: Signum
        :+: Abs) a deriving (Functor, Monad)
```

and you can then define

```
 instance Num (Numerical a)
```

which might be totally useless, but I find very cool.  It does let you define other things like

```
 class Pretty f where
    pretty :: f String -> String

 instance Pretty Mult where
    pretty (Mult a b) = a ++ "*" ++ b
```

and similar for all the rest of them.

It is a useful design stategy: list the things you want your monad to do ==> define functors for each operation ==> figure out what some of its algebras should be ==> define those functors for each operation ==> make it fast.

Making it fast is hard, but we have some tricks.  Trick 1 is to just wrap your free monad in `Codensity` (the "go faster button") but when that doesn't work you want to get rid of the free representation.  Remember when we had

```
runState (Pure a) s = (a,s)
runState (Impure (Get f)) s = runState (f s) s
runState (Impure (Set s next)) _ = runState next s
```

well, this is a function from `Free StateF a` to `s -> (a,s)` just using the result type as our definition for state seems reasonable...but how do we define the operations?  In this case, you know the answer, but one way of deriving it would be to think in terms of what Conal Elliott calls type class morphisms.  You want

```
runState (return a) = return a
runState (x >>= f) = (runState x) >>= (runState f)
runState (set x) = set x
runState get = get
```

which makes it pretty easy

```
runState (return a) = (Pure a) = \s -> (a,s)

runState (set x) 
   = runState (Impure (Set x (Pure ()))) 
   = \_ -> runState (Pure ()) x
   = \_ -> (\s -> (a,s)) x
   = \_ -> (a,x)

runState get
  = runState (Impure (Get Pure))
  = \s -> runState (Pure s) s
  = \s -> (s,s)
```

which is pretty darn helpful.  Deriving `>>=` in this way can be tough, and I won't include it here, but the others of these are exactly the definitions you would expect.

Comment: +1, but `:.:` should really be `:+:` - what you have is functor coproduct, composition would look like `newtype (f :.: g) x = C (f (g x))`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is `Impure`? It appears out of nowhere. Is it constructor `Free` of [`Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free)?

Comment: I used `Free f a = Pure a | Impure (f (Free f a))` as my assumed definition.  People seem to not be able to reach a consensus as to what the name of the second data constructor should be

Comment: I like `Impure`, because it says nothing more than "it's that other constructor that's not `Pure`." :)

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question as it is stated, most of the familiar monads that you didn't mention in the question are not themselves free monads. Philip JF's answer alludes to how you can relate a given monad to a new, free monad, but the new monad will be "bigger": it has more distinct values than the original monad. For example the real `State s` monad satisfies `get >>= put  =  return ()`, but the free monad on `StateF` does not. As a free monad, it does not satisfy extra equations by definition; that is the very notion of freeness.

I'll show that the `Reader r`, `Writer w` and `State s` monads are not free except under special conditions on `r`/`w`/`s`.

Let me introduce some terminology. If `m` is a monad then we call any value of a type `m a` an (`m`-)action. We call an `m`-action trivial if it is equal to `return x` for some `x`; otherwise we call it nontrivial.

If `m = Free f` is any free monad on a functor `f`, then `m` admits a monad homomorphism to `Maybe`. This is because `Free` is functorial in its argument `f` and `Maybe = Free (Const ())` where `Const ()` is the terminal object in the category of functors. Concretely, this homomorphism can be written

```
toMaybe :: Free f a -> Maybe a
toMaybe (Pure a) = Just a
toMaybe (Impure _) = Nothing
```

Because `toMaybe` is a monad homomorphism, it in particular satisfies `toMaybe (v >> w)  =  toMaybe v >> toMaybe w` for any `m`-actions `v` and `w`. Now observe that `toMaybe` sends trivial `m`-actions to trivial `Maybe`-actions and nontrivial `m`-actions to the nontrivial `Maybe`-action `Nothing`. Now `Maybe` has the property that `>>`ing a nontrivial action with any action, in either order, yields a nontrivial action (`Nothing >> w  =  v >> Nothing  =  Nothing`); so the same is true for `m`, since `toMaybe` is a monad homomorphism that preserves (non)triviality.

(If you prefer, you could also verify this directly from the formula for `>>` for a free monad.)

To show that a particular monad `m` is not isomorphic to any free monad, then, it suffices to find `m`-actions `v` and `w` such that at least one of `v` and `w` is not trivial but `v >> w` is trivial.

`Reader r` satisfies `v >> w  =  w`, so we just need to pick `w = return ()` and any nontrivial action `v`, which exists as long as `r` has at least two values (then `ask` is nonconstant, i.e., nontrivial).

For `Writer w`, suppose there is an invertible element `k :: w` other than the identity. Let `kinv :: w` be its inverse. Then `tell k >> tell kinv  =  return ()`, but `tell k` and `tell kinv` are nontrivial. Any nontrivial group (e.g. integers under addition) has such an element `k`. I presume that the free monads of the form `Writer w` are only those for which the monoid `w` is itself free, i.e., `w = [a]`, `Writer w ~ Free ((,) a)`.

For `State s`, similarly if `s` admits any nontrivial automorphism `f :: s -> s` with inverse `finv :: s -> s`, then `modify f >> modify finv  =  return ()`. Any type `s` with at least two elements and decidable equality has such automorphisms.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote up a proof that the list monad is not free in a [posting to the haskell-cafe mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-January/126026.html), based on the insights in Reid's answer:

Recall that we can construct, for any functor f, the free monad over f:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Roll (f (Free f a))
```

Intuitively, Free f a is the type of f-shaped trees with leaves of type a.
The join operation merely grafts trees together and doesn't perform any
further computations. Values of the form (Roll _) shall be called
"nontrivial" in this posting.

Some of the usual monads are in fact free monads over some functor:

- The Tree monad is the free monad over the functor `Pair`, where
  `data Pair a = MkPair a a`. The intuition as Pair-shaped trees
  is most strong in this example. Every parent node has a pair of
  children.
- The Maybe monad is the free monad over the functor `Unit`, where
  `data Unit a = MkUnit`. In the graphical picture parent nodes have a
  `Unit` of children, so no children at all. So there are exactly two
  `Unit`-shaped trees: the tree consisting only of a leaf (corresponding
  to `Just _`) and the three consisting of a childless parent node
  (corresponding to `Nothing`).
- The `Identity` monad is the free monad over the functor `Void`,
  where `Void a` is a type without constructors.
- The `Partiality` monad is the free monad over `Maybe`.
- The `Writer [r]` monad is the free monad over the functor `(r,)`.
  In an `(r,)`-shaped tree, a parent node is decorated with a value
  of type `r` and has exactly one child node. Traversing such a path
  yields a list of `r`'s and a leaf value of type `a`, so in total
  a value of type `([r],a) = Writer r a`.

  (In particular, `Free (r,) ()` is isomorphic to `[r]`. This observation
  led to the claim that the list monad is free. But this claim is false
  and indeed doesn't follow from the observation. To show that a monad `m`
  is free, one has to exhibit a monad isomorphism `forall a. m a -> Free f a`
  for some functor `f`. In contrast, exhibiting an isomorphism of `m a` with
  `Free (f a) ()` is neither sufficient nor required.)

Even more monads are quotients of free monads. For instance, `State s` is
a quotient of `Free (StateF s)`, where

```
data StateF s a = Put s a | Get (s -> a).
-- NB: This functor is itself a free functor over a type constructor
-- which is sometimes called StateI [1], rendering Free (StateF s) what
-- Oleg and Hiromi Ishii call a "freer monad" [2].
```

The quotient is exhibited by the following monad morphism, which gives
semantics to the purely syntactical values of the free monad.

```
run :: Free (StateF s) a -> State s a
run (Pure x)         = return x
run (Roll (Put s m)) = put s >> run m
run (Roll (Get k))   = get >>= run . k
```

This point of view is the basis of the operational package by apfelmus [1]
and is also talked about in an StackOverflow thread [3]. It's the main
reason why free monads are useful in a programming context.

So, is the list monad a free monad? Intuitively, it's not, because the
join operation of the list monad (concatenation) doesn't merely graft
expressions together, but flattens them [4].

Here is a proof that the list monad is not free. I'm recording it since
I've been interested in a proof for quite some time, but searching for
it didn't yield any results. The threads [3] and [5] came close, though.

In the free monad over any functor, the result of binding a nontrivial
action with any function is always nontrivial, i.e.

```
(Roll _ >>= _) = Roll _
```

This can be checked directly from the definition of `(>>=)` for the free
monad or alternatively with Reid Barton's trick of exploiting a monad
morphism to Maybe, see [3].

If the list monad was isomorphic-as-a-monad to the free monad over some
functor, the isomorphism would map only singleton lists `[x]` to values of
the form `(Pure _)` and all other lists to nontrivial values. This is
because monad isomorphisms have to commute with "return" and `return x`
is `[x]` in the list monad and `Pure x` in the free monad.

These two facts contradict each other, as can be seen with the following
example:

```
do
    b <- [False,True]  -- not of the form (return _)
    if b
        then return 47
        else []
-- The result is the singleton list [47], so of the form (return _).
```

After applying a hypothetical isomorphism to the free monad over some
functor, we'd have that the binding of a nontrivial value (the image
of `[False,True]` under the isomorphism) with some function results in a
trivial value (the image of `[47]`, i.e. `return 47`).

Cheers,
Ingo

[1] http://projects.haskell.org/operational/Documentation.html

[2] http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf

[3] [What monads can be expressed as Free over some functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641864/what-monads-can-be-expressed-as-free-over-some-functor)

[4] https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html

[5] https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/50zvyb/why_is_liststate_not_a_free_monad/

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it'd be worth copying the answer here, for the benefit of readers and for the (very unlikely) case the link will become dead eventually.

Comment: @Petr: Did so. Feel free to fixup the links if they bother you, I have to run now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All monads can be expressed as the Free Monad. Their additional properties (like MonadFix and Cont) could be stripped off that way because the Free Monad is not a Free MonadFix or Free Cont.

The general way is to define Functor's fmap in terms of liftM and then wrap Free around that Functor.
The resulting Monad can be reduced to the previous/actual Monad by specifying how the functions `return` and `join` (Pure and Impure) have to be mapped to the actual Monad.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there such thing as a free MonadFix or a free MonadCont?

Comment: @petr-pudlak: Sure. Free Something is the simplest implementation put on top of something smaller so that it fulfills the requirements without specifying that implementation. (In a non-mathematical way speaking.)

Comment: Mathematically I know that it's possible, I was more curious if it's possible to express/implement such thing in Haskell.

Comment: @petr-pudlak: I'm sure that that is possible. But I'm still not in the Category of Gurus who can answer that right out of the box. (So far I only tried it with MonadFix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636048#14750027)