# Flat lists and free monads

Tags: list, haskell, ocaml, monads, category-theory

I am trying to convince myself that the List monad (the one with flat lists, concatenation of lists and map element-wise) is not a free monad (to be precise, the free monad associated to some functor T). As far as I understand, I should be able to achieve that by

- first finding a relation in the monad List between the usual operators fmap, join etc,
- then showing that this relation does not hold in any free monad over a functor T, for all T.

What is a peculiar relation that holds in the List monad, that sets it apart from the free monads? How can I handle step2 if I don't know what T is? Is there some other strategy to show that flat lists are not free?

As a side note, to dispell any terminology clash, let me remark that the free monad associated to the pair functor is a tree monad (or a nested list monad), it is not the flat List monad.

*Edit*: for people acquainted with the haskell programming language, the question can be formulated as follows: how to show that there is no functor T such that List a = Free T a (for all T and up to monad isomorphism)?

Comment: Free monads are generalised externally-labelled trees; `a`s appear in the `Return` constructor, not in the `Free` constructor. Lists are internally-labelled; they have `a`s all along the list, not just at the leaves.

Comment: @Hodgson I am not sure that I understand your comment. There are free monads that are not trees. The monoid of integers, for example, can be realized as the free monad associated to the identity functor on the category of one object (and a single morphism).

Comment: Are you referring to `type Nat = Free Identity ()`? That's a tree with a branching factor of 1 (because `Identity a` contains one `a`). `Free ((->) r)` is a tree with a branching factor of `r`, `Free (Const Void)` is a tree with a branching factor of 0. Etc

Comment: Yes that's the point. Consider the integers (the mathematical one, usually implemented as big int), they can be built as a tree or a free monad, as you just mentioned. Why is it not so for flat lists? I am not asking for a philosophical answer, but for some explicit construct (preferably a relation) that shows that List monad cannot be isomorphic to a free monad.

Answer (score 3):

(Adapted from my [post in a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41809366/4533618).)

Here is a full proof why the list monad is not free, including a bit of context.

Recall that we can construct, for any functor `f`, the free monad over `f`:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Roll (f (Free f a))
```

Intuitively, `Free f a` is the type of `f`-shaped trees with leaves of type `a`.
The join operation merely grafts trees together and doesn't perform any
further computations. Values of the form `(Roll _)` shall be called
"nontrivial" in this posting. The task is to show that for no functor `f`, the monad `Free f` is isomorphic to the list monad.

The intuitive reason why this is true is because the
join operation of the list monad (concatenation) doesn't merely graft
expressions together, but flattens them.

More specifically, in the free monad over any functor, the result of binding a nontrivial
action with any function is always nontrivial, i.e.

```
(Roll _ >>= _) = Roll _
```

This can be checked directly from the definition of `(>>=)` for the free
monad.

If the list monad would be isomorphic-as-a-monad to the free monad over some
functor, the isomorphism would map only singleton lists `[x]` to values of
the form `(Pure _)` and all other lists to nontrivial values. This is
because monad isomorphisms have to commute with "return" and `return x`
is `[x]` in the list monad and `Pure x` in the free monad.

These two facts contradict each other, as can be seen with the following
example:

```
do
    b <- [False,True]  -- not of the form (return _)
    if b
        then return 47
        else []
-- The result is the singleton list [47], so of the form (return _).
```

After applying a hypothetical isomorphism to the free monad over some
functor, we'd have that the binding of a nontrivial value (the image
of `[False,True]` under the isomorphism) with some function results in a
trivial value (the image of `[47]`, i.e. `return 47`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with the free monad being applied to a type in particular which seems to be the case given the way you consider the `Nat` example given in the comments, then `List` can indeed be described using `Free`:

```
type List a = Free ((,) a) ()
```

The underlying idea here is that a `List a` is a `Nat` where each `Suc` node has been labelled with an `a` (hence the use of the `(a,)` functor rather than the `Identity` one).

Here is a small module witnessing the isomorphism together with an example:

```
module FreeList where

import Data.Function
import Control.Monad.Free

type List a = Free ((,) a) ()

toList :: [a] -> List a
toList = foldr (curry Free) (Pure ())

fromList :: List a -> [a]
fromList = iter (uncurry (:)) . fmap (const [])

append :: List a -> List a -> List a
append xs ys = xs >>= const ys

example :: [Integer]
example = fromList $ (append `on` toList) [1..5] [6..10]
```

Comment: You'll notice thought that bind for `List a` is not the bind for `[]`. So you may want to reconsider accepting `Free f` to be applied to a fixed type like in `Nat`.

Comment: That's clever! It's quite surprising that the `<<` Free operator corresponds to appending Lists. Now if this construction was a monad isomorphism, `Free.(<<) ` would correspond to the standard `[].(<<)` operator, which is quite different from append. Still there is one instance where it works, namely for `a = ()`, in which case we recover Nat.