# MonadFix instance for interpreter monad transformer generated by FreeT?

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad, monadfix

I have a simplified version of the standard interpreter monad transformer generated by `FreeT`:

```
data InteractiveF p r a = Interact p (r -> a)

type Interactive p r = FreeT (InteractiveF p r)
```

`p` is the "prompt", and `r` is the "environment"...one would run this using something like:

```
runInteractive :: Monad m => (p -> m r) -> Interactive p r m a -> m a
runInteractive prompt iact = do
  ran <- runFreeT iact
  case ran of
    Pure x -> return x
    Free (Interact p f) -> do
      response <- prompt p
      runInteractive prompt (f resp)

instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (FreeT (InteractiveF p r)) m a)
mfix = -- ???
```

I feel like this type is more or less just a constrained version of `StateT`...if anything, an `Interactive p r IO` is I think a constrained version of `IO`...I think...but... well, in any case, my intuiton says that there should be a good instance.

I tried writing one but I can't really seem to figure out.  My closest attempt so far has been:

```
mfix f = FreeT (mfix (runFreeT . f . breakdown))
  where
    breakdown :: FreeF (InteractiveF p r) a (FreeT (InteractiveF p r) m a) -> a
    breakdown (Pure x) = x
    breakdown (Free (Interact p r)) = -- ...?
```

I also tried using a version taking advantage of the `MonadFix` instance of the `m`, but also no luck --

```
mfix f = FreeT $ do
  rec ran <- runFreeT (f z)
      z   <- case ran of
               Pure x -> return x
               Free iact -> -- ...
  return -- ...
```

Anyone know if this is really possible at all, or why it isn't?  If it is, what's a good place for me to keep on looking?

---

Alternatively, in my actual application, I don't even really need to use `FreeT`...I can just use `Free`; that is, have `Interactive` be just a monad and not just a monad transformer, and have

```
runInteractive :: Monad m => (p -> m r) -> Interactive p r a -> m a
runInteractive _ (Pure x) = return x
runInteractive prompt (Free (Interact p f) = do
    response <- prompt p
    runInteractive prompt (f response)
```

If something is possible for this case and not for the general FreeT case, I would also be happy :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636048/is-it-possible-to-implement-monadfix-for-free

Comment: @shang question is pretty different..the other one is asking if a polymorphic generic mfix can be written, while I'm asking about a concrete type :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you already had an interpreter for `Interactive`.

```
interpret :: FreeT (InteractiveF p r) m a -> m a
interpret = undefined
```

It would be trivial to write a `MonadFix` instance:

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (FreeT (InteractiveF p r) m) where
    mfix = lift . mfix . (interpret .)
```

We can directly capture this idea of "knowing the interpeter" without committing to an interpreter ahead of time.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data UnFreeT t m a = UnFree {runUnFreeT :: (forall x. t m x -> m x) -> t m a}
--   given an interpreter from `t m` to `m` ^                          |
--                                  we have a value in `t m` of type a ^
```

`UnFreeT` is just a `ReaderT` that reads the interpreter.

If `t` is a monad transformer, `UnFreeT t` is also a monad transformer. We can easily build an `UnFreeT` from a computation that doesn't require knowing the interpreter simply by ignoring the interpeter.

```
unfree :: t m a -> UnFreeT t m a
--unfree = UnFree . const
unfree x = UnFree $ \_ -> x

instance (MonadTrans t) => MonadTrans (UnFreeT t) where
    lift = unfree . lift
```

If `t` is a monad transormer, `m` is a `Monad`, and `t m` is also a `Monad`, then `UnFree t m` is a `Monad`. Given an interpreter we can bind together two computations that require the interpeter.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

refree :: (forall x. t m x -> m x) -> UnFreeT t m a -> t m a
-- refree = flip runUnFreeT
refree interpreter x = runUnFreeT x interpreter

instance (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => Monad (UnFreeT t m) where
    return = lift . return
    x >>= k = UnFree $ \interpreter -> runUnFreeT x interpreter >>= refree interpreter . k
```

Finally, given the interpreter, we can fix computations as long as the underlying monad has a `MonadFix` instance.

```
instance (MonadTrans t, MonadFix m, Monad (t m)) => MonadFix (UnFreeT t m) where
    mfix f = UnFree $ \interpreter -> lift . mfix $ interpreter . refree interpreter . f
```

We can actually do anything the underlying monad can do, once we have the interpreter. This is because, once we have an `interpreter :: forall x. t m x -> m x` we can do all of the following. We can go from `m x` through `t m x` all the way up to `UnFreeT t m x` and back down again.

```
                      forall x.
lift               ::           m x ->         t m x
unfree             ::         t m x -> UnFreeT t m x
refree interpreter :: UnFreeT t m x ->         t m x
interpreter        ::         t m x ->           m x
```

#### Usage

For your `Interactive`, you'd wrap the `FreeT` in `UnFreeT`.

```
type Interactive p r = UnFreeT (FreeT (InteractiveF p r))
```

Your interpreters would still be written to produce a `FreeT (InteractiveF p r) m a -> m a`. To interpret the new `Interactive p r m a` all the way to an `m a` you'd use

```
interpreter . refree interpreter
```

The `UnFreeT` no longer "frees the interpreter as much as possible". The interpreter can no longer make arbitrary decisions about what to do wherever it wants. The computation in `UnFreeT` can beg for an interpreter. When the computation begs for and uses an interpreter, the same interpreter will be used to interpret that portion of the program as was used to start interpreting the program.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to write a `MonadFix m => MonadFix (Interactive p r)` instance.

Your `InteractiveF` is the base functor of the well studied [Moore machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine). A Moore machine provides an output, in your case the prompt, then determines the next thing to do based on an input, in your case the environment. A Moore machine always outputs first.

```
data MooreF a b next = MooreF b (a -> next)
    deriving (Functor)
```

If we follow [C. A. McCann's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14640129/414413) about writing `MonadFix` instances for `Free` but constrain ourselves to the specific case of `Free (MooreF a b)`, we will eventually determine that if there's a `MonadFix` instance for `Free (MooreF a b)` then there must exist a function

```
mooreFfix :: (next -> MooreF a b next) -> MooreF a b next
```

To write this function, we must construct a `MooreF b (f :: a -> next)`. We don't have any `b`s to output. It's conceivable that we could get a `b` if we already had the next `a`, but a Moore machine always outputs first.

#### Like the let in State

You can write something close to `mooreFfix` if you are reading just one `a` ahead.

```
almostMooreFfix :: (next -> MooreF a b next) -> a -> MooreF a b next
almostMooreFfix f a = let (MooreF b g) = f (g a)
                      in (MooreF b g)
```

It then becomes imperative that `f` be able to determine `g` independently of the argument `next`. All of the possible `f`s to use are of the form `f next = MooreF (f' next) g'` where `f'` and `g'` are some other functions.

```
almostMooreFFix :: (next -> b) -> (a -> next) -> a -> MooreF a b next
almostMooreFFix f' g' a = let (MooreF b g) = f (g a)
                          in (MooreF b g)
                          where
                              f next = MooreF (f' next) g'
```

With some equational reasoning we can replace `f` on the right side of the `let`

```
almostMooreFFix :: (next -> b) -> (a -> next) -> a -> MooreF a b next
almostMooreFFix f' g' a = let (MooreF b g) = MooreF (f' (g a)) g'
                          in (MooreF b g)
```

We bind `g` to `g'`.

```
almostMooreFFix :: (next -> b) -> (a -> next) -> a -> MooreF a b next
almostMooreFFix f' g' a = let (MooreF b _) = MooreF (f' (g' a)) g'
                          in (MooreF b g')
```

When we bind `b` to `f' (g' a)` the `let` becomes unnecessary and the function has no recursive knot.

```
almostMooreFFix :: (next -> b) -> (a -> next) -> a -> MooreF a b next
almostMooreFFix f' g' a = MooreF (f' (g' a)) g'
```

All of the `almostMooreFFix`es that aren't `undefined` don't even need a `let`.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced by this argument...in haskell, we have laziness..  We have MonadFix for State, so so we `a -> s -> (a, s)` to `s -> (a, s)`...for example, what if your function outputs a `b` that is constant and doesn't depend on `next`...or what if it outputs something that can be evaluated partially (like a list, where the first two elements are constant), and the rest depends on a `next` that we generate with the first two...laziness means that we don't need *all* `next` *immediately* to get *some* of `b`...

Comment: @JustinL. We don't have any `b`s, we don't have any `a`s and we don't have any `next`s. If we had a `next ` we could get a `b`. We can get an `a` before we need to return a `next`. The `b` we return can't possibly be defined in terms of that `a`; if it were we'd have poked a hole in the purity of functions; applying the function returned in the `MooreF` constructor would change the value of the `b` returned in the same constructor.

Comment: @JustinL. As for a "`b` thas is constant and doesn't depend on `next`", `moreFFix` must be written `forall b.`, which is why I say, "we don't have any `b`s". The only value we know `b` can take on short of something returned from the function is `undefined` which is worse than useless.

Comment: "Not having any `b`s" doesn't always stop us in haskell; `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` works, despite us not having any `a`s; `fix f = f (fix f)`

Comment: @JustinL., I do not understand this well enough to know if Cirdec is right, but I do understand Cirdec's abilities well enough to know you should take what they say seriously.

Comment: @dfeuer I've been wrong before; usually many times per day. The onus to check arguments before believing them is always on the reader.

Comment: @JustinL. I've added what happens if you do an analog of `a -> s -> (a, s)` to `s -> (a, s)`. Separately, in `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` not having any `a`s doesn't stop us because we *have a way to get* `a`s if we only had any `a`s. When we don't have any `a`s or `b`s, a function `( a-> b)` doesn't help us make either the `a`s we need to use the function or the `b`s.

Comment: @Cirdec, I just mean your argument deserves careful inspection.

Comment: thank you all, I think I'm starting to see.  One thing that seems to be weird to me in the end is that I'm basically using this to "purify" code that runs in `IO`...where all I ever do with the `IO` is block, put things to stdout, read in the answer, and move on with the answer.  This happens to be MonadFix just fine and works like I expect.  But how come when I try to just isolate the part of IO that I need, how come I apparently lose this ability?

Comment: Also, can we write instances if we popped in concrete types, like `Interact Int Int` ...?

Comment: @JustinL. It's because you've removed the parts of IO that are needed to write a `MonadFix` instance. `fixIO` is based on the ability to read references that haven't been written yet. It's implemented in terms of `MVar`s and `unsafeInterleaveIO`. `Free` is "freeing the interpreter as much as possible", which prevents us from doing a few other things. I believe we can write a `MonadFix` instance if we commit to a concrete interpreter. I'll post another answer about how to add `MonadFix` to `Free` without committing to a concrete interpreter.