# Autos, Arrows and Free Monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, arrows, free-monad

I've read two great series of articles about [Autos](http://blog.jle.im/entry/intro-to-machines-arrows-part-1-stream-and) and [Free Monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) and I'd like to combine this two techniques somehow.

I'd like to have something like:

```
data ProgramF a = Get (String -> a) | Set String a
instance Functor ProgramF where ...
type Program = Free ProgramF

get' :: Program String
get' = liftF $ Get id

set' :: String -> Program ()
set' s = liftF $ Set s ()

auto1 :: AutoM Program () String
auto1 = arrM \_ -> get'

auto2 :: AutoM Program String ()
auto2 = arrM \s -> set' s

auto3 :: AutoM Program () ()
auto3 = auto1 >>> auto2

...
```

But there are some problems, for example `ArrowLoop` requires `Program` to be an instance of `MonadFix` which is not possible as far as I understand.

So my questions are:

- Are there ways to make `Auto` and `Free` work together?
- And if not, maybe there are other ways to achieve the goal?

Note: I'm pretty new to functional programming, so I understand from little to nothing in theory.

**Update:**

In one of the comments it was mentioned that `Auto` is itself a form of fixpoint and I can use `ProgramF` directly with it. So I guess that the type of `Auto` should look something like this:

```
newtype Auto f a b = Auto (a -> f (b, (Auto f a b)))
```

But the problem now is that I can't figure out how to compose two `Auto`s without `f` being a `Monad`.

*My end goal is to have some composable pieces of code with internal state and a way to purify my code hiding all `IO` effects (like `log` or `getLine`) in some kind of interpreter.*

So I guess my real question is: **how can I implement something described above?**

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong and there is a better way. Can someone please give a simple example or provide some links to something similar?

Comment: So far, your only actual complaint about `Free` is that you can't implement `MonadFix` or `ArrowLoop`. Do you need to?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29161923/414413

Comment: @DanielWagner Actually I don't know for sure will I need it or not, but I have some thoughts about how it can be useful. And I don't want to discover one day that I really need it, but can't have it :)
@Cirdec Thanks, I'll take a look.
Btw can something not exactly the same, but similar (I mean purification part) be implemented without `Free`, for example only with `Arrow`?

Comment: `Auto` is itself a form of fixpoint. Why not use `ProgramF` rather than `Program` with it?

Comment: The [machines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines) library builds `Process`es from the base functor of state transducers http://stackoverflow.com/q/27997155/414413

Comment: @Cirdec Thanks for this links, I'll certainly take a look. It looks like a lot of info to wrap my head around.

Comment: @gallais Can you please give an example of how to do it? Or maybe give links to such examples?